# multipart/form-data not working anymore, missing filename

Tags: swift, multipartform-data

I have a function to upload an image using multipart/form-data that was working before, today it stopped working for whatever reason. I got error = "Missing file name in your upload form.";
status = 400;

I tested with Xcode 13 and 12, no luck

anybody experiencing the same issues? if so, how did you fix it? thanks

```
func requestNativeImageUpload(image: UIImage) {

    let url = URL(string: "https://api.pixlab.io/facedetect")
    let boundary = "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)"
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)

    let parameters = ["key" : "YOUR API KEY"]

    guard let mediaImage = Media(withImage: image, forKey: "file") else { return }

    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = [
                "X-User-Agent": "ios",
                "Accept-Language": "en",
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)",
                "ApiKey": "YOUR API KEY"
            ]

    let dataBody = createDataBody(withParameters: parameters, media: [mediaImage], boundary: boundary)
    request.httpBody = dataBody

    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response {
            print(response)
        }

        if let data = data {
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
                print(json)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        }.resume()
}

func createDataBody(withParameters params: [String: String]?, media: [Media]?, boundary: String) -> Data {

    let lineBreak = "\r\n"
    var body = Data()

    if let parameters = params {
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            body.append("--\(boundary + lineBreak)")
            body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\(lineBreak + lineBreak)")
            body.append("\(value + lineBreak)")
        }
    }

    if let media = media {
        for photo in media {
            body.append("--\(boundary + lineBreak)")
            body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(photo.key)\"; filename=\"\(photo.fileName)\"\(lineBreak)")
            body.append("Content-Type: \(photo.mimeType + lineBreak + lineBreak)")
            body.append(photo.data)
            body.append(lineBreak)
        }
    }

    body.append("--\(boundary)--\(lineBreak)")

    return body
}


extension Data {
    mutating func append(_ string: String) {
        if let data = string.data(using: .utf8) {
            append(data)
        }
    }
}


struct Media {
    let key: String
    let fileName: String
    let data: Data
    let mimeType: String

    init?(withImage image: UIImage, forKey key: String) {
        self.key = key
        self.mimeType = "image/jpg"
        self.fileName = "\(arc4random()).jpeg"

        guard let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1) else { return nil }
        self.data = data
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "status = 400" tell you?

Comment: Tomato san, I know it means bad request, but it was working before, tried with other methods and still not working. I'm suspecting of the end point now....unless you believe it's something else in my code

Comment: Where does a guy named 'image' come from?

Comment: from an ImagePicker (struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable)

Comment: issue solved. The problem was the endpoint, code was correct. 
"Issue has been identified & resolved moments ago. Please test your code again, and report back if you please.

Thanks for helping us fixing the issue!"